# How to use RxJs distinctUntilChanged?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm getting started with RxJs (using the v5 beta), but somehow I can't figure out how to work with `distinctUntilChanged`. The output from the code below if I run it in babel-node is

```
[ 'a', 1 ]
{ key: 'a', state: 1 }
Next:  { value: 42 }
Completed
```

That is not what I would expect. Why is only one entry passing `distinctUntilChanged`? I would expect the output to be

```
[ 'a', 1 ]
[ 'a', 0 ]
[ 'a', 1 ]
{ key: 'a', state: 1 }
{ key: 'a', state: 2 }
{ key: 'a', state: 0 }
{ key: 'a', state: 1 }
Next:  { value: 42 }
Next:  { value: 24 }
Completed
```

Here's the code

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

Observable.of(['a', 1], ['a', 1], ['a', 0], ['a', 1])
  .distinctUntilChanged(x => x[1])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))

Observable.of({key: 'a', state: 1}, {key: 'a', state: 2}, {key: 'a', state: 0}, {key: 'a', state: 1})
  .distinctUntilChanged(x => x.state)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))

Observable.of({value: 42}, {value: 42}, {value: 24}, {value: 24})
  .distinctUntilChanged(x => x.value)
  .subscribe(
    function (x) {
      console.log('Next: ', x)
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err)
    },
    function () {
      console.log('Completed')
    }
  )
```

The [links](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/operators.md) in the v5 docs for these functions appear to be dead

------ edit -----

Some additional debugging:

```
Observable.of(['a', 1], ['a', 1], ['a', 0], ['a', 1])
  .do(x => console.log('before', x))
  .distinctUntilChanged(x => x[1])
  .do(x => console.log('after', x))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

output:

```
before [ 'a', 1 ]
after [ 'a', 1 ]
[ 'a', 1 ]
before [ 'a', 1 ]
before [ 'a', 0 ]
before [ 'a', 1 ]
```

Comment: Also, for this kind of debugging question, you should include the expected behaviour and ideally show some attempts at debugging.

Comment: OK I've added the expected output

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got an answer [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1188). Basically the function signature changed from (key selector, comparator) to (comparator, key selector).

This is how the example is done in v5:

```
Observable.of(['a', 1], ['a', 1], ['a', 0], ['a', 1])
  .distinctUntilChanged(null, x => x[1])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xqmndgr7/1/) with your code is Rxjs V4. You will see that it works correctly.

```
Observable.of(['a', 1], ['a', 1], ['a', 0], ['a', 1])
  .distinctUntilChanged(x => x[1])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
...
```

So it seems to be something with the new beta version. Here are the specs for [distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/distinctUntilChanged-spec.ts). The operator itself seems to be working as in version 4.

To test things out, I recommend you trace the output of each function by inserting a `.do(function(x){console.log(x)})` in between operators. I can only think of the `of` operator maybe passing on only the last element of the array.

Comment: alright, can you try now with `Observable.from` instead of `Observable.of`  (put all your arrays in an array though)? Can you also try the same with `of` but change `'a', 1` to `'b', 1`. It seems `of` operator takes either only the last or the first argument you pass.

Comment: I can confirm that v4 works. Looks like v5 is broken or at least their own documentation is incorrect. The code at "with key selector" [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md) has the same problem as I'm having in v5, so I guess I'll create an issue on github for that

Comment: Well it is a beta version right. Don't forget to upvote the answers you found useful, and accept those who solved your problem.

Comment: So it turned out it was not a bug but an API change. I better stick to v4 until the docs are available, so I have a clue of what I'm doing.