# FormControl distinctUntilChanged() not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having a hard time making `distinctUntilChanged` work in this next scenario. I made an asynchronous validator, which uses a service to check if a user exists with the given username. This validator is bound, as a directive, to an input.

```js
class ValidateUniqueUsernameDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors> {
    return control.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      tap(value => {
        debugger;
        console.log(value);
      }),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(value => {
        return this.userService.getUserByUsername(value).pipe(
          map(user => {
            const usernameIsAvailable = user === undefined;
            return usernameIsAvailable
              ? null
              : { usernameAvailability: { value: control.value } };
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Calling the service results in network requests, so I debounced the validation, and, to further lessen them, I tried adding `distinctUntilChanged`, so that, as user @Kld explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889851/formcontrol-detectchanges-why-use-distinctuntilchanged), user changes within the debounce time **back** to the previous value wouldn't trigger a new request. However, that's not what's happening. I don't understand what's happening, as the tapped value seems to be the same.

I'm on Angular 6, using RxJS 6. Thank you for your help!

Comment: everytime a new value is sent for checking, your `validate` function is called, a new observable is generated and the previous one is unscubscribed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add debounce time to an async validator in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919011/how-to-add-debounce-time-to-an-async-validator-in-angular-2)

Comment: @n00dl3, makes sense. then [why use distinctUntilChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889851/formcontrol-detectchanges-why-use-distinctuntilchanged) with FormControl?

Comment: Kld is totally right. This is a valid point that doesn't apply to form validation but to other actions (eg: auto-saving forms). @cosh

Comment: how so? if every time the user enters a new character, a new observable is generated, then distinctUntilChanged will always compare to a new value. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the point: it does not apply to form validation. **But** it applies to other things, like I said, you can use dynamic forms to create a form that has an auto-save behavior, and you don't want to make a duplicated request. @cosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
class ValidateUniqueUsernameDirective implements AsyncValidator {

   private lastValue=null;
   private lastResult=null;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors> {
      if(lastValue!==control.value){
        //do your validation and save result
      }else{
         // return last result or clear error state
      }
  }
}
```

You can also add timeouts to perform request after user stops typing etc.