# How to use debounceTime() and distinctUntilChanged() in async validator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I want to add `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` in my async validator.

```js
mockAsyncValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => {
          console.log(value);  // log works here
          return this.mockService.checkValue(value).pipe(response => {
            console.log(response);  // log did not work here
            if (response) {
              return { invalid: true };
            }
            return null;
          })
        })
      );
  }
```

The code above did not work, the form status becomes `PENDING`.
But when I use `timer` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007974/10684507), the code works, but I can't use `distinctUntilChanged` then.

```js
return timer(500).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.mockService.checkValue(control.value).pipe(response => {
        console.log(response);  // log works here
        if (response) {
          return { invalid: true };
        }
        return null;
      })
    })
  );
```

I tried to use `BehaviorSubject` like

```js
debouncedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

and use it in the `AsyncValidatorFn`, but still not work, like this:

```js
this.debouncedSubject.next(control.value);
return this.debouncedSubject.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(), // did not work
                          // I think maybe it's because of I next() the value
                          // immediately above
                          // but I don't know how to fix this
  take(1), // have to add this, otherwise, the form is PENDING forever
           // and this take(1) cannot add before debounceTime()
           // otherwise debounceTime() won't work
  switchMap(value => {
    console.log(value); // log works here
    return this.mockService.checkValue(control.value).pipe(response => {
        console.log(response);  // log works here
        if (response) {
          return { invalid: true };
        }
        return null;
      }
    );
  })
);
```

Comment: It turns out that `distinctUntilChanged()` seems not really apply to form async validations. References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51380618/10684507) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889851/10684507).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a new pipe is being built every time the validatorFn executes as you are calling `pipe()` inside the validatorFn. The previous value isn't capture for discinct or debounce to work.  What you can do is setup two `BehaviourSubjects` externally, `termDebouncer` and `validationEmitter` in my case.

You can set up a factory method to create this validator and thereby re-use it. You could also extend `AsyncValidator` and create a class with DI setup. I'll show the factory method below.

```
export function AsyncValidatorFactory(mockService: MockService) { 
  const termDebouncer = new BehaviorSubject('');
  const validationEmitter = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null);
  let prevTerm = '';
  let prevValidity = null;

  termDebouncer.pipe(
        map(val => (val + '').trim()),
        filter(val => val.length > 0),
        debounceTime(500),
        mergeMap(term => { const obs = term === prevTerm ? of(prevValidity) : mockService.checkValue(term);
          prevTerm = term; 
          return obs; }),
        map(respose => { invalid: true } : null),
        tap(validity => prevValidity = validity)
    ).subscribe(validity => validationEmitter.next(validity))


  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    termDebouncer.next(control.value)
    return validationEmitter.asObservable().pipe(take(2))
  }
}
```

**Edit**: This code excerpt is from a use case other than Angular form validation, (React search widget to be precise.) the pipe operators might need changing to fit your use case.

**Edit2**: `take(1)` or `first()` to ensure that the observable completes after emitting the validation message. `asObservable()` will ensure that a new observable will be generated on the next call. You might also be able to skip `asObservable()` and just `pipe()` as the pipe operator branches the async pipeline and creates a new observable from there onwards. You might have to use `take(2)` to get past the fact that a behaviourSubject is stateful and holds a value.

**Edit3**: Use a merge map to deal with the fact `distinctUntilChanged()` will cause the observable to not emit and not complete.

Comment: I think `debounceTime()` should be called before `distinctUntilChanged()`. And since the `val` in `termDebouncer`'s type is `string` trivially, it seems that you can use `val.trim()` directly in the first `map()`.

Comment: This is an excerpt from one of my projects where the value could be a `number` or `string`. I've copied and pasted some and added some. Yep you are right on the `distinctUntilChanged()`

Comment: I found that although `debounceTime()` and `distinctUntilChanged()` work fine now, it will make the form stuck in `PENDING` status. `take(1)` or `first()` not seems to be the right way to fix this since either of them will "complete" the observer and never accept the value emit from the control after.

Comment: no it should be okay to use them because the statement, `validationEmitter.asObservable()` is called every time the input is validated and you can pipe it there.

Comment: You're right on this, I wrongly put the `take()` pipe onto `termDebouncer`. Now the async validation can complete. But here comes another dilemma situation: if `distinctUntilChanged()` fails, the `mockService` won't execute so nothing will emit to the `validationEmitter`, and form stucks in `PENDING` status again.

Comment: I've made a change. Look, I've shown you how to capture and reuse behaviour subjects which is what was holding you back originally. I can't keep helping you account for every possible scenario. That's your job. For example: this will not work if there's a network error. This link explains all the operators you need to make observables work, the rest is up to  you. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators