# Rxjs `distinctUntilChanged()` appears to not be working

Tags: rxjs, lodash, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In an rxjs stream, I'm using `distinctUntilChanged` with lodash's `isEqual` to filter out duplicate values. However it *appears* to not be working as expected. Take the following code snippet

```js
import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es';

let cachedValue: any;

function testFn(observableVal: Observable<any>) {
  return observableVal
    .pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(isEqual),
      tap(val => {
        const equal = isEqual(cachedValue, val);
        console.log('"output":', equal, cachedValue, val);
        cachedValue = val;
      })
    )
}
```

In this example, I would expect that `const equal` inside the `tap` function would never `=== true`. I would expect that `distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)` would filter out any values where `isEqual(cachedValue, val) === true` --> meaning that `const equal === false` always. However, console output shows:

```
"output": false undefined [ContactList]
"output": true [ContactList] [ContactList]
"output": true [ContactList] [ContactList]
"output": true [ContactList] [ContactList]
```

Do I misunderstand something fundamental about how the `distinctUntilChanged()` operator works? I've posted a simplified example because the actual rxjs stream is very complex, but I wouldn't expect the complexity to make any difference in so far as `const equal` should always `=== false` in the `tap` operator.

I'm just trying to understand what's going on, so any info is appreciated. Thanks!

#### Update

It should be noted that if I change the code to:

```js
function testFn(observableVal: Observable<any>) {
  return observableVal
    .pipe(
      filter(val => {
        const equal = isEqual(cachedValue, val);
        cachedValue = val;
        return !equal;
      }),
      tap(val => {
        console.log('"output":', val);
      })
    )
}
```

Then the filtering works as expected. [I was under the impression that `distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)` was equivalent to:](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)

```
filter(val => {
  const equal = isEqual(cachedValue, val);
  cachedValue = val;
  return !equal;
})
```

Am I mistaken / misunderstanding the [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) operator?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured it out! Thanks to a comment in an [rxjs issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2980#issuecomment-338235298): I had accidently subscribed to the observable multiple times (which shouldn't have happened). The multiple `console.log` instances were coming from different subscription instances.

Comment: Thanks for keeping your question up John! Helped me see how to write my own custom DistinctUntilChanged() operator

Comment: It was useful to me, since I had the same issue. I forgot that I had subscribed twice in my template. One of the pitfalls of relying on `tap` to do what `subscribe` should do.

Comment: Useful to me.  I'm going to go eyeball the merge() that I place my distinctUntilChanged observable in.  @Wilt maybe you should just consider deleting your comment, it is not of any use for other ending up here.

Comment: Just if someone else stumbles over this with the same problem: distinctUntilChanged() does not work with FormControl value changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889851/formcontrol-detectchanges-why-use-distinctuntilchanged

Answer (score 2):

In case someone will get here because of similar issue as I had - keep in mind that custom comparator function should return `false` to pass the `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

In other words this comparator will allow to pass when no changes in `someProp`:

```
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.someProp !== curr.someProp)
```

and this - only if `someProp` was changed:

```
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.someProp === curr.someProp)
```